# How to draw image in memory manually in pyglet?

Tags: pyglet

In pyglet, I want to create an image buffer in memory, then set the bytes manually, then draw it. I tried making a 3x3 red square like this in my draw() function:

```
imageData = pyglet.image.ImageData(3, 3, 'RGB', [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ])
imageData.blit(10, 10)
```

...but at runtime, Python complains:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 9: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Is this the right approach? Am I missing a step? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the error corresponds with the code you have posted above? I do not know python but I don't see anything you have posted above with 9 arguments.

AFAIK it looks like one of your arguments are not using the correct type.

Comment: I agree with Code Assassin. The error seems to have to do with what you typed, wrong arguments?

Comment: Well, I guess I am just assuming it is the problem as the error doesn't show up if I comment those lines... http://pastebin.com/iveDhYcB    is the full source

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, but as the error tells you, you must use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) instead of Python types for it.

RGB values are unsigned byte triplets, which means `c_ubyte` in ctypes, also available in `pyglet.gl` as `GL_ubyte`. So you can do this:

```
pixels = [
    255, 0, 0,      0, 255, 0,      0, 0, 255,     # RGB values range from
    255, 0, 0,      255, 0, 0,      255, 0, 0,     # 0 to 255 for each color
    255, 0, 0,      255, 0, 0,      255, 0, 0,     # component.
]
rawData = (GLubyte * len(pixels))(*pixels)
imageData = pyglet.image.ImageData(3, 3, 'RGB', rawData)
```

The above is the recommended `ctypes` syntax, which generates an array of `GLubyte` with the right size and then populates it with your pixel data.

Comment: I've changed your colors a little from all red to illustrate the pixel order on rendering.